# Fontsize Change for Cell in Material UI Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the font size of every Cell in Material UIs Table. The below fails hard.

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    fontSize: '200pt',
  },
  body: {
    fontSize: '200pt',
  },
};

...

<TableCell className={styles.body}/>
```

Tried following this link, but didn't help either, unfortunately:

[How to increase the font size for the Table component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301906/how-to-increase-the-font-size-for-the-table-component)

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';


 const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      root: {
        fontSize: '200pt',
      },
      table: {
        fontSize: '200pt',
      },
    }));


function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];
```

add the body class to table tag not in TableCell

```
  export default function SimpleTable() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Table className={classes.table}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```